# How can I display the number of checked checkboxes in a textbox from a column in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, checkbox, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a DataGridView with a CheckBox column in it. (This is an inventory system.) The check is used to move serial numbers of items from one location to another in our company.

I also have a textbox where, as of now, the employee enters the number of items he is moving, then checks the appropriate serial numbers, and moves the items.

I would like the number in the textbox to be generated depending on how many serial numbers are checked. Is it even possible? I've tried about a hundred different solutions at this point and they all either end in strange errors, or give me no results whatsoever.

Comment: So to be clear, you just need to update a textbox with the number of checkboxes checked in the datagridview?  Does this need to update as you check/uncheck items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this should be close enough. I read an article or ten about this once when I was having the same issue. The trick is to commit the edit immediately when the box is clicked on, which will then trigger the `CellValueChanged` event. You can then pick up the count from there.

This should update the textbox as you check and uncheck the checkbox:

```
private void dgv_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgv.IsCurrentCellDirty && dgv.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name == "MyCheckColumn")
        dgv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}

private void dgv_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1) //just a guard for the header row
        return;

    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "MyCheckColumn")
        textBox.Text = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Count(r => Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells["MyCheckColumn"].Value)).ToString();
}
```

Hopefully the Linq works. If not, you'll have to do it the old-fashioned `foreach` way with a sum variable. I know the `DataGridViewRowCollection` can be finicky sometimes.

Comment: Where is the 'WriteoffData.CommitEdit...' coming from? I don't seem to have anything with that.. Do I need to add a library?

Comment: @HerNameIsEllie It's a bad paste, sorry. See my edited version.

Comment: Sigh, I'm now getting some weird error that doesn't seem to be related. "System.FormatException: Formatted value of the cell has a wrong type." I think I messed something up while I was trying to do this earlier (I have lots of edits). Any idea where that's coming from?

Comment: @HerNameIsEllie Ouch, are you trying to programmatically parse the value of a cell, specifically using the `CellFormatting` event? If so, make sure you're setting `e.Value` to the type specified in `e.DesiredType` (I think it's usually `string` but could be wrong)

Comment: I don't think I have a CellFormatting event... Should I?

Comment: @HerNameIsEllie No, it's just one common source of that kind of error. I think it may just be time to start commenting out code until you find the source...

Comment: Or, if you're databound, you will have another problem entirely which may cause this - that the default `GetFormattedValue` for the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` really only wants a a)Boolean column bound to it or b)a string, where TrueValue and FalseValue are set properly. This could be where the error is coming from too and equally ugly to fix